# How to enable address sanitizer at godbolt.org

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

I am trying to enable address sanitizer at godbolt.org with `-fsanitize=address`, but get error:

```
==3==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xdfff0001000 (15392894357504) bytes at address 2008fff7000 (errno: 12)
==3==ReserveShadowMemoryRange failed while trying to map 0xdfff0001000 bytes. Perhaps you're using ulimit -v
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/5GDtrr

How can I enable address sanitizer correctly?

Comment: In case you ever file a request at Godbolt - please add a link to your answer.

Comment: @yugr I added link to answer with a comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By design Asan allocates a huge amount of virtual memory (20 Tb on x86_64 machines) at start (details [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm)). This may be a problem if [overcommit is disabled](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2016-September/050860.html) or [virtual memory is limited with ulimit -v](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2449).

In both cases there's nothing Asan can do - you'll need to raise this with Godbolt VM maintainers in https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues

Comment: Thanks. Got reply: https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/1703#issuecomment-557838344